# Unresolved external symbol while linking class files, Visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2019, unresolved-external

There are three files in a project: 
**HAT_array.h:**

```
#pragma once

class HAT_array {
public:
    HAT_array();
};
```

**HAT_array.cpp:**

```
#include "HAT_array.h"

inline HAT_array::HAT_array() {
    return;
}
```

**test.cpp:**

```
#include "HAT_array.h"

int main(void) {
    HAT_array HAT;
}
```

While building the solution I receive an unresolved external symbol error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: HashedArrayTree, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>HAT_array.cpp
1>test.cpp
1>test.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: __thiscall HAT_array::HAT_array(void)" (??0HAT_array@@QAE@XZ)
1>C:\Users\myros\Desktop\HashedArrayTree\Release\HashedArrayTree.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Done building project "HashedArrayTree.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: `inline` means internal linkage, i.e. nothing marked as such won't be seen outside of `HAT_array.cpp` where it's defined. So that's what you tried. In `test.cpp` you try to call the constructor which is not seen. Remove the `inline`

Comment: You should for the most part not use `inline` anyways. The compiler will not use it any more as a hint to inline code. ***Because the meaning of the keyword inline for functions came to mean "multiple definitions are permitted" rather than "inlining is preferred", that meaning was extended to variables.*** There is more info here: [https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/inline)

Comment: @AlexLarionov You can put your answers in the lovely answer section found below the question. Comments are for requesting clarification. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why did you mark the definition `inline`?

That gives it internal linkage, so no other translation units can "see" it.

It can be useful to put it on definitions when you want to put those definitions in header files, but that's not what you've done here.

**Remove `inline`.**

Answer (score 2):

`inline` keyword means internal linkage, i.e. nothing marked as such won't be seen outside of `HAT_array.cpp` (or strictly speaking this *translation unit*) where it's defined.

So in `test.cpp` you try to call the constructor definition which is not seen. Remove the `inline` keyword, and don't use it, as pointed out by @drescherjm. You're unlikely to get any advantage of it, unless you really know what you're doing.